# create multiple chart.js in the same web page?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

So I figured how to draw multiple charts on the same page, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this than specifying a name for each div?

snippet of the code:

```
  <body>
<div style="width:1080px;margin:0 auto;">
<div style="width:80%">
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
<div  style="width:80%">
  <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</div>
</div>
```

```
      var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
  new Chart.Scatter (ctx, {
    data: build_data_set(1),
    options: set_options(1)
  });

  var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
  new Chart.Scatter(ctx2, {
    data: build_data_set(0),
    options: set_options(0)
  });
```

so if for example i have 30 charts i need to draw, i need to specify 30 div? (canvas,canvas2, canvas3...,canvas30) or is there a better way to do this with a for loop maybe?

After a lot a lot of digging, I made it work. here is the code:

```
      function create_chart(set_data, options, canvas){
    var ctx=document.getElementById(canvas).getContext('2d');
     new Chart.Line(ctx, {data:set_data, options:options});

  }
  var in_canvas = document.getElementById('graph-container');
  for (k=0; k<param.length; k++){
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    in_canvas.appendChild(newDiv);
    var newCan = document.createElement('canvas');
    newDiv.appendChild(newCan);
    newCan.id = "canvas"+[k];
    canv="canvas"+[k];
    var data_test=build_data_set(k)
    create_chart(build_data_set(k),set_options(k),canv);


}
```

Comment: You can create and insert HTML elements programmatically. `var t = document.createElement("canvas");` Now you can do `document.body.appendChild(t);` and `new Chart.Scatter(t.getContext("2d"), ...);`

Comment: i can't understand how to work this, can you please write a more specified answer ?

Comment: You should write an answer below, not in the question.